# invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘unsigned int*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c

I was given this code, which was supposed to compile, by my teacher. It's supposed to calculate PI by using threads. Then we are supposed to time the program and/or add appropriate timing system calls to the code. Run different threads and create a plot that compares time and number of threads... The problem is, I have no idea how to fix this problem. I have never dealt with something like this and I didn't build the code myself so I'm confused on how to fix it.

The compiler says the problem is coming from:

```
rand_no_y = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;
                                       ^
```

and

```
rand_no_x = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;
```

The whole code is below:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


#define MAX_THREADS 512

void *compute_pi( void * );


//int sample_points;
int total_hits;
int total_misses;
int hits[ MAX_THREADS ];
int sample_points;
int sample_points_per_thread;
int num_threads;



int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  /* local variables */
  int ii;
  int retval;
  pthread_t p_threads[MAX_THREADS];
  pthread_attr_t attr;
  double computed_pi;

  /* initialize local variables */
  retval = 0;


  pthread_attr_init( &attr );
  pthread_attr_setscope( &attr, PTHREAD_SCOPE_SYSTEM );

  /* parse command line arguments into sample points and number of threads */
  /* there is no error checking here!!!!! */
  sample_points = atoi(argv[1]);
  num_threads = atoi(argv[2]);

  /* uncomment this block if you want interactive input!!!! */
  /* if so...comment out the two statements above */
  /*  
  printf( "Enter number of sample points: " );
  scanf( "%d", &sample_points );
  printf( "Enter number of threads: " );
  scanf( "%d%", &num_threads );
  */

  total_hits = 0;
  sample_points_per_thread = sample_points / num_threads;

  for( ii=0; ii<num_threads; ii++ )
    {
      hits[ii] = ii;
      pthread_create( &p_threads[ ii ], &attr, compute_pi, (void *) &hits[ii] );
    }

  for( ii=0; ii<num_threads; ii++ )
    {
       pthread_join( p_threads[ ii ], NULL );
       total_hits += hits[ ii ];
    }

   computed_pi = 4.0 * (double) total_hits / ((double) (sample_points));


   printf( "Computed PI = %lf\n", computed_pi );


  /* return to calling environment */
  return( retval );
}


void *compute_pi( void *s )
{
  int seed;
  int ii;
  int *hit_pointer;
  int local_hits;
  double rand_no_x;
  double rand_no_y;

  hit_pointer = (int *) s;
  seed = *hit_pointer;
  local_hits = 0;

  for( ii=0; ii < sample_points_per_thread; ii++ )
    {
      rand_no_x = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;

      rand_no_y = (double) (rand_r( &seed ))/(double)RAND_MAX;

      if(((rand_no_x - 0.5) * (rand_no_x - 0.5) +
      (rand_no_y - 0.5) * (rand_no_y - 0.5)) < 0.25)

    local_hits++;

      seed *= ii;
    }

  *hit_pointer = local_hits;
  pthread_exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Check the type `rand_r` is supposed to take, and give it to it.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: You can see that `hit_pointer` points to `int`, but `rand_r` requires a pointer to `unsigned int`.  So provide an unsigned_int for the seed.  (e.g `unsigned int *hit_pointer = s;  unsigned int seed = *hit_pointer;   ... rand_r(&seed) ...`)

Comment: IMO, `.../(double)RAND_MAX` is off-by-1.  Should be the mathematical equivalent of `/(double)(RAND_MAX + 1LL)`

Answer (score 0):

With `int seed`, `&seed` is an `int *`.

[`rand_r(unsigned int *seedp)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r) expects a `unsigned *`

Use `unsigned` for `seed, ii` and others,